# How to correctly upload image and video to Azure storage container as blob using Axios in React Native application?

Tags: javascript, azure, react-native, axios, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a React Native app where I have requirement of uploading an image or a video to Azure storage account as blob. Currently I am working on image upload but I would like to add video in this question as video will be next step. I have tried so many ways to upload image to Azure storage but I can't get image uploaded correctly from the RN app using Axios. I am generating upload url with SAS token so I can share that url from backend server with device to be able to upload an image or video from the device. I used `Postman` to test the url and everything is fine there! With `Postman` I can upload an image as binary body. I used `Postman`'s code generation that shows `Axios` code example but I am not sure what it means by ***file contents here***. Let me back up a bit.

In this React Native app I am using [react-native-image-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker) to pick image from gallery and passing the path to a helper class and I am using [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) to get image just to make sure that it exists and everything and also I am getting `base64` string from *RNFS*. Now I have both image path and base64 string of image that I want to upload to Azure server using Axios. I tried few things. One of the thing is example code from postman but as I said, I am not sure how to pass file content as data object shown in example code which is,

```js
const axios = require('axios');
let data = '<file contents here>'; // <--- I don't know this

let config = {
  method: 'put',
  url: 'https://azure.blob.url/container/blob?sastoken=1234',
  headers: { 
    'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob', 
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I looked for the answer on internet to see if someone has done this way or not! Well I found so many sample code but neither of them worked for me. I might be doing something wrong but I don't know what. One of the way I tried was to use `fetch()` by passing both `base64` string and path with `file://` (***currently focusing on Android to get the code working and will work on iOS part later but I would appreciate if code example/suggestion/help can be for both Android and iOS***) differently to get blob and use it as data object in Axios and it still didn't work!

One of the other option I tried was to use `RNFS.upload()` as suggested [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs#file-upload-android-and-ios-only). That didn't work for my test as it would fail with error and there is an issue created on Github [here](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/799). There is a fix mentioned in conversation which can be found [here](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/pull/944/commits/03512913eddba3753920714da4ca79f8699112b3). But it is not merged in master branch and I don't know how to get that patch installed plus I would rather work with a patched version.

Other than these methods, I tried `FormData()` and few other ways which I don't have code example at the moment. So I am looking for help here by posting my own question with hope to get help and in future if someone is trying to follow similar steps, they can find help!